# Unique input IDs in Freeform

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace, freeform

Apologies if this has already been brought up but shouldn't each input have a unique id? I assumed Freeform would prepend the input ids with the form id or something but it seems it just duplicates ids everywhere. Doesn't seem great for what is a pretty expensive plugin.

Comment: Do not hesitate to contact their [support](https://docs.solspace.com/craft/freeform/v3/support.html). They are very pro-active, and open for feature-fix like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for Freeform 3:

Preventing **duplicated field id**:
[Set a custom field id prefix.](https://docs.solspace.com/craft/freeform/v3/template-functions/freeform.form.html#param-fieldidprefix) Using the form handle might be a good id, as long as you're not using the same form twice on the same page.

Preventing **duplicated form id**:
Manually adjust the [form id parameter](https://docs.solspace.com/craft/freeform/v3/template-functions/freeform.form.html#parameters) to something unique.

Comment: Thanks, the field ID prefix looks like it should do the trick. I didn't realise there was the option.